# Speedup capacitor for compensating stray capacitance

Tags: operational-amplifier, parasitic-capacitance

I may be wrong here but I think C1 and C2 charge to different polarities, so when the output changes, C2 supplies the required charge(+ or -) to C1 quickly.

For example: If the output is \$+V_{sat}\$, the `C1` can have `+Q1` charge and `C2` can have `-Q2` charge. Then when the output changes to \$-V_{sat}\$, the `C2` supplies negative charge to `C1` quickly charging it to `-Q1`.

If I'm right so far, wouldn't this arrangement cause an issue as briefly ALL the output voltage may appear across R1 when the charge across C2 is \$0\$?

[image]

Comment: What's the problem if all the output voltage appears across R1? Are you using resistors  rated below the supply voltage of the circuit or something? I've personally never seen a resistor rated anywhere remotely near the Vcc of a typical opamp supply voltage of 15V, or even 36V, or even 100V.

Comment: Oh is it okay? Not about ratings, I feel it disturbs functionality itself. Doesn't it cause some undesired tripping if \$v_{in}\$ is also changed ?

Comment: Tripping of what? This is an op-amp, a linear device. There is no tripping. Polarities change at  some point, sure, but it's a linear change that happens smoothly on either side of zero.

Comment: by tripping i mean unwanted change of output voltage when \$v_{in}\$ goes above/below the voltage across R1

Comment: Op-amps are linear devices...it's not like a comparator. It's going to change smoothly as the input changes smoothly.

Comment: Oh I sort of see your question. There is positive feedback, not negative feedback.

Comment: ^yeah...........

Comment: To me C2 is just acts as a low impedance route for high frequencies to bypass the RC constant of R2/C1. Polarities at the non-inverting input don't really change direction sudenly or anything like that to cause your tripping. They just move in the direction they were always going to move either slower or faster.

Comment: Exactly my question...since the impedance of C2 is low when switching, almost all the output voltage appears across R1

Comment: I don't see why that would cause a mistripping though because the dV/dT of R1 doesn't change at all. The full voltage cannot appear across R1 until C1 is charged, but C2 is charging at the same time so the full voltage can't appear. So the end result is that the full voltage never appears across R1. I think you're forgetting that C1 has to charge up too and the voltage across R1 and C1 are the same.

Comment: Oh I see your point more positive or more negative as reference voltage during switching doesn't affect the functionality as \$v_{in}\$ needs to reverse its direction to cause the output to change again. Awesome! I get it thank you so much:))

Comment: Yeah, for tripping to happen the trip point suddenly has to momentarily move in the opposite direction that it is supposed to move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full voltage doesn't actually appear across R1 because C1 has to charge up, and the voltage of R1 and C1 are the same. But as C1 is charging up, C2 is also charging up making a capacitive divider (along with the R1/R2 resistive divider) so the full supply voltage never actually appears across R1.

And during all this, the direction of the voltage change (dV/dT) never actually changes so no tripping happens. For the output to trip over itself, the reference threshold has to suddenly and momentarily reverse direction as it is moving and cross the input voltage as it does so. If the threshold is moving in the same direction (either towards or away from the input) the entire time, you still get a single, clean point where the output changes.